# Explain the output when a integer is given as input

Tags: c++

-explain output when an integer is an input

-why -47 increments the value if input is 5

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

        string s;
        cin>>s;
        cout<<(*s.begin())-47;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is the output equal to 3 instead of 5 as you wrote?

Comment: why people are flagging me if i dont know the concept

Comment: There are many inadequate especially among low-qualified programmers that like to down-vote. Usually it is the only thing that they can do.:)

Comment: now because of them i am banned for 5 days from asking questions.what's wrong in my question.

Comment: This is not a stellar question, but the close reason is bogus. I voted to reopen. As for the hate, this sounds like unredacted homework question - which are not very welcome here. Just a poor choice of words, I would say.

Comment: @Danny  Maybe that someone considers the question as unclear or that you changed your post that it now differs of the previous. I can not answer instead others. As for me it seems that I am the only who up-voted your question.:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ASCII character 2 has code 50. So 50 - 47 will result in 3. 
Thus if in statement

```
   cin>>s;
```

you enetered 2

then in statement

```
    cout<<(*s.begin())-47;
```

expression `*s.begin()-47`  that is equivalent to `'2' - 47` is converted to type `int` due to the integer promotion and is equal to 3 ( '2' - 47 => 50 - 47 == 3).

Take into account that call `s.begin()` returns iterator that points to the first character of the string and `*s.begin()` yields the character itself.